# What does it mean to be "stuck" on an old SKD (3.7.12) with a big app?

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, deprecated

We're working on a large-scale app that's tied to an annual release. Right now, we're using SDK 3.7.12, and we're wondering about a couple of things:

End-of-Life for SDK 3.7.12: Does anyone know where we can find the official end-of-life documentation for this SDK version? We need to ensure it'll be supported at least until our next major release.

App Store Support: How can we confirm that this SDK version will still allow us to push updates to app stores in the coming months? We've got a few post-release updates planned, and it's crucial that we're able to push them through.

Roughly, until mid-late 2024 including updates

I made a couple of attempts at migrating the codebase to null safety, it seems like an attainable task, but with much incremental work. I succeded in compiling the app in release mode after changing over 300 files, but to reach the stability we need for our users would be a complicated task with no guarantee of success.

What do you think?

Thanks!

We are going to keep three branches up and running (as a safety net):

- old SDK, untouched old codebase
- old SDK, code base migrated to null safety
- new SDK, code base migrated and updated

Today we'll push out a minor change to ensure the latest xcode and the old SDK still play nicely together.

Comment: There are no EOLs because the support is technically community-support which never expires.  In the past, a few urgent fixes have been backported to older versions, but for the most part, anything official out of Google just moves forward.